# Test class failing for striphtml method

Tags: apex, trigger, code-coverage, failing-tests

I need some help with test class which is failing.Here is my code

```
trigger striptext on customobj__c (before insert, before update) {
for customobj__c atxt:trigger.new)
{ 
if (atxt.Record_Type_Name__c == 'Test')
  if (atxt.Status__c !='')
     atxt.Status_Text__c = atxt.Status__c.stripHtmlTags();
  }
}

  @isTest
  public class teststriptext  {
    Id RecordTypeIdstatus = Schema.SObjectType.Status__c.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Test').getRecordTypeId();

    Status__c teststatus = new Status__c();
    teststatus.RecordTypeId =RecordTypeIdstatus;
    teststatus.Daily_Status__c='<p>This is a test record.</p><p><span style="color: rgb(112, 110, 107);">This is a test record.</span></p><p><br></p>';
    insert teststatus;

    teststatus.Status_Text__c = teststatus.Status__c.stripHtmlTags();
    update teststatus;

    Test.startTest();
    System.assertEquals('This is a test record. This is a test record.',teststatus.Status_Text__c);
    Test.stopTest();
}
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Well, how is it failing? What's the error and on which line? Do the assertions pass? If you debug the asserted values, what do you see?

Comment: There is probably spurious trailing or leading space. Call `trim()` on the strings before you assert their values.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with any clarifications. That's not what comments are for.

Answer (score 2):

You have this substring:

```
'...record.</p><p><span style="color: rgb(112, 110, 107);">This...'
```

Note that there is no whitespace between. That will convert to:

```
'...record.This...'
```

But you set your expected value as:

```
 '...record. This...'
```

Just a note, your test would be a lot cleaner if you use constants instead of magic strings. Something like the following would be a lot easier to test:

```
final String A = 'Some content';
final String B = 'More content';
final String WITH_HTML = '<p>' + A + '</p><p>' + B + '</p>';

MyObject__c record = new MyObject__c(FieldWithHtml__c=WITH_HTML);

Test.startTest();
    insert record
Test.stopTest();

system.assertEquals(A+B, record.FieldSansHtml__c, 'The html tags should be stripped out');
```

Additional notes:

- You should have a *separate testMethod* for the insert and update case.
- The above tests only insert. In your update case, make sure you do not set the `Status__c` field until after insert.
- Your current code is vulnerable to a `NullPointerException`. Your `if` condition should check `String.isNotBlank` instead of looking only for the empty string.